# How to Update HTML Style Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-agility-pack

I have a c# .net core 2.2 application that I am trying to parse an HTML page and edit some style attributes on.

I am using HTML Agility Pack

In my HTML I have an Id that has several styles.

```
<td id="bannerTop" class="alert alert-warning" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: top; color: #fff; font-weight: 500; text-align: center; border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; background-color: #FF9F00; margin: 0; padding: 20px;" align="center" bgcolor="#FF9F00" valign="top">
```

I want to call this element "bannerTop" and edit the style background-color

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(selectedTemplate.HtmlTemplateString);

var bannerTop = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("bannerTop");
bannerTop.Attributes["style"].Value = "background-color: #0000FF";
```

But that overwrites all style attributes, how can I just edit one of them? Do I need to do a manual parsing of the string that `bannerTop.Attributes["style"]` returns or is there an easier way that HTML Agility Pack allows to edit a single style?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to add a style attribute to Html using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062495/better-way-to-add-a-style-attribute-to-html-using-htmlagilitypack)

Comment: Will the Add function update existing attributes?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the `CssStyleCollection` class referenced in the duplicate question.  That is a built-in object that should be able to handle the more granular CSS parsing for you.

Comment: I don't believe CssStyleCollection is available in .Net Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the styles from the attribute and then loop over them to manually change the specific item of styles.

I'd split on the ";" then the ":" to get name/value pairs. Loop over them, lowercase the name and change the value if it matches `bgcolor`.Otherwise, append original value to `newStyles`.

```
var bannerTop = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("bannerTop");
string oldStyle = bannerTop.Attributes["style"].Value;
string newStyles = "";
foreach (var entries in oldStyle.Split(';'))
{
    var values = entries.Split(':');
    if (values[0].ToLower() == "bgcolor")
    {                                                                   
        values[1] = "#0000FF";
        newStyles += String.Join(':', values) + ";";
    }
    else
    {
        newStyles += entries + ";";
    }

}

bannerTop.Attributes["style"].Value = newStyles;
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I was hoping there was a built in function in HTML Agility Pack but looks like no. Thanks for the feedback though.